# How do I share locks between two processes working on the same region of shared memory?

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory, ipc, shared-memory

I'm wondering how to do this (using C++98). Here's my scenario: I have process A and process B. Process A allocates a large buffer in shared memory and splits it into a fixed number of chunks. It then uses a series of structs like these to represent each chunk:

```
struct Chunk
{
    Lock lock; //wrapper for pthread_attr_t and pthread_mutex_t
    char* offset; //address of the beginning of this chunk in the shared memory buffer
};
```

The Lock when constructed does this:

```
pthread_mutexattr_init(&attrs);
pthread_mutexattr_setpshared(&attrs, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);
pthread_mutex_init(&lock,&attrs); //lock is pthread_mutex_t and attrs is pthread_mutexattr_t
```

the lock method when called does this:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
```

It uses placement new when creating the above "Chunk"s into the beginning of the shared memory buffer like this:

```
char* mem; //pointer to the shared memory
Chunks[i] = new (mem) Chunk; //for i = {1..num chunks}
mem += sizeof(Chunk);
```

Then it assigns offsets and proceeds to write into the rest of the buffer through it's lifetime. Each time it is writing in the chunk corresponding to one of the aboves it grabs the chunks lock and releases it when done.

Now process B comes up and maps the same shared memory buffer into memory and attempts to retrieve the chunks like this:

```
Chunk** chunks = reinterpret_cast<Chunk**)(mem); //mem being the pointer into the shared memory
```

then it tries to operate on the shared memory by scanning around the different chunks and also trying to make use of the lock if needed.

I am getting strange crashes when I run this in which the chunks** is garbage and am wondering if the Lock would work across the processes as well or if there are any other caveats I'm ignoring in the simple steps above? Is having the SHARED pthread attr enough or do I need to use an entirely different breed of lock?

Comment: "it tries to operate on the shared memory by scanning around the different chunks and also trying to make use of the lock if needed." you need to show how you use the lock because you're probably doing it wrong.

Comment: I added details on the locking

Comment: Note that you don't need to create a separate `pthread_mutexattr_t` for each lock -- you can create a single attr (once) and reuse it to initialize each lock.  After initialization, the lock does not refer back to the attr (so you don't need to keep it around); the attr is just a convenient way of batching up a lot of options that are read when the lock is created, rather than giving `pthread_mutex_init` dozens of arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pull a region of shared memory into a process, it generally will NOT be located at the same virtual address as in other processes that access the shared memory.  So you can't just store the raw pointers into the shared memory and expect them to work meaningfully.

So in your case, even though the `Chunk` is in shared memory, the `offset` pointer within each chunk is not meaningful in any other process.

One solution is to use offsets from the beginning of the shared memory chunk

```
struct Chunk {
    pthread_mutex_t  lock;
    size_t           offset;
};

char *base; // base address of shared memory
char *mem;  // end of in-use shared memory

Chunk *chunks = reinterpret_cast<Chunk *>(mem);  // pointer to array in shared memory
for (int i = 0; i < num_chunks; i++) {
    // initialize the chunks
    new(mem) Chunk;
    mem += sizeof(Chunk); }
// set the offsets to point at some memory
for (int i = 0; i < num_chunks; i++) {
    chunks[i].offset = mem - base;
    mem += CHUNK_SIZE; // how much memory to allocate for each chunk?
}
```

Now in B you can just do

```
Chunk *chunks = reinterpret_cast<Chunk *>(base);
```

but in either process, to access the data of a chunk, you need `base + chunks[i].offset`

Alternately, you can use a [package that manages the shared memory allocation for you and ensures that it gets mapped at the same address in every process](https://github.com/ChrisDodd/shm_malloc).

Comment: I'm trying to store the actual structures (by allocating them with placement new) and then reinterpret casting wherever that gets mapped in the other process as a pointer to that type of structure.

Comment: @PalaceChan The problem is that seemingly you are storing pointers on the shared memory area (like `Chunk::offset`). On the shared memory area you should store only offsets that are relative to something that is inside the shared memory area (for example the beginning of the shared memory). Although I'm not a boost fan there are a set of boost namespaces/classes for IPC and shared memory management like `boost::interprocess` and the pointer that can be used even on shared memory areas (because it stores the pointer as a relative offset) is `boost::interprocess::offset_ptr`.

Comment: @pasztorpisti Oh I see, yes I think I would just change the offset to be a relative ptrdiff_t then as I would rather not pull in a boost lib for something which seems relatively simple like the above. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Chris Dodd Yes agree on integral offsets within the Chunk structure, let me go ahead and try that

Comment: @PalaceChan It is still advisable to wrap your ptrdiff_t or whatever offset integer into a pointer class. You just store your integer into it relative to the this pointer of the pointer object itself (this is the location of the offset integer itself) and whenever someone asks for the actual pointer (for example by calling the operator-> or operator*) of your pointer class then you just add the offset to the this pointer of your pointer class instance. Encapsulation helps you to avoid later errors. Always encapsulate if possible (even the mutex and other classes).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to my comments I also provide a very basic offset_ptr implementation. I agree that making a simple project dependent on something like boost may be an overkill but even until reaching a certain project size where you decide to switch to a more serious set of libraries it is worth wrapping critical things like offset pointers. Wrapping helps you to centralize your offset handler code and also to guard yourself with asserts. A simple offset_ptr template that doesn't handle all cases can still be much better than hand-coded offset+pointer manipulator code that is copy pasted everywhere and its basic implementation without attempting to be comprehensive is:

```
template <typename T, typename OffsetInt=ptrdiff_t>
class offset_ptr
{
    template <typename U, typename OI> friend class offset_ptr;
public:
    offset_ptr() : m_Offset(0) {}
    offset_ptr(T* p)
    {
        set_ptr(p);
    }
    offset_ptr(offset_ptr& other)
    {
        set_ptr(other.get_ptr());
    }
    template <typename U, typename OI>
    offset_ptr(offset_ptr<U,OI>& other)
    {
        set_ptr(static_cast<T*>(other.get_ptr()));
    }
    offset_ptr& operator=(T* p)
    {
        set_ptr(p);
        return *this;
    }
    offset_ptr& operator=(offset_ptr& other)
    {
        set_ptr(other.get_ptr());
        return *this;
    }
    template <typename U, typename OI>
    offset_ptr& operator=(offset_ptr<U,OI>& other)
    {
        set_ptr(static_cast<T*>(other.get_ptr()));
        return *this;
    }
    T* operator->()
    {
        assert(m_Offset);
        return get_ptr();
    }
    const T* operator->() const
    {
        assert(m_Offset);
        return get_ptr();
    }
    T& operator*()
    {
        assert(m_Offset);
        return *get_ptr();
    }
    const T& operator*() const
    {
        assert(m_Offset);
        return *get_ptr();
    }
    operator T* ()
    {
        return get_ptr();
    }
    operator const T* () const
    {
        return get_ptr();
    }

private:
    void set_ptr(const T* p)
    {
        m_Offset = p ? OffsetInt((char*)p - (char*)this) : OffsetInt(0);
    }
    T* get_ptr() const
    {
        return m_Offset ? (T*)((char*)this + m_Offset) : (T*)nullptr;
    }

private:
    OffsetInt m_Offset;
};

offset_ptr<int> p;
int x = 5;

struct TestStruct
{
    int member;
    void func()
    {
        printf("%s(%d)\n", __FUNCTION__, member);
    }
};

TestStruct ts;
offset_ptr<TestStruct> pts;

int main()
{
    p = &x;
    *p = 6;
    printf("%d\n", x);

    ts.member = 11;
    if (!pts)
        printf("pts is null\n");
    pts = &ts;
    if (pts)
        pts->func();
    pts = nullptr;
    if (!pts)
        printf("pts is null again\n");

    // this will cause an assert because pts is null
    pts->func();
    return 0;
}
```

It may contain some operator functions that are pain in the ass to write if you are not used to implement pointer stuff but this is really simple compared to a full fledged pointer implementation of a complex lib like boost, isn't it? And it makes the pointer (offset) manipulator code much nicer! There is no excuse for not using at least a wrapper like this!

Wrapping the locks and other stuff is also fruitful even if you do it for yourself without external libs because after writing/using the locks with bare native api for 2-3-4 times it truns out that your code will look much nicer if you use a simple wrapper with a ctor/destructor/lock()/unlock() not to mention the centralized lock/unlock code that can be guared with asserts and occasionally you can put in debug info to the lock class (like the id of the last locker thread to debug deadlocks easier...).

So don't omit wrappers even if you are rolling your code without std or boost.

Comment: this is pretty cool thanks, unfortunately as i suspected it seems my pthreads are segfaulting on the call to lock..the rest of the chunk state looks fine within gdb from both processes and even the lock struct in gdb seems alike.

Comment: @PalaceChan double check your pointers. Your original post contained some completely buggy codepieces, for example this: `Chunk** chunks = reinterpret_cast<Chunk**)(mem);`. Make sure to eliminate all of these bugs. In both processes log out the address of the shared memory area and also the this pointers of the locks when you call their lock method. BTW, do you use a fixed number of chunks (compile time constant) or variable number of chunks?